# Reverse array with for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Quick JavScript question. In the following pieces of code I'm reversing the array `arr` that's being passed to the function `reverseArray`.

In the first piece of code, it looks like that the local variable `arr` keeps changing even though inside the loop I am operating on the variable `newArr` which hold the initial value of `arr`. Hence the loop fails when arr.length reaches the values `3`.

```
function reverseArray (arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    var inArr = arr;
    console.log(inArr);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {      
        newArr[i] = inArr.pop(i);       
    }   
    return newArr;
}
reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]);

// OUTPUT: ["F", "D", "E"]
```

On the other hand, if I store `arr.length` on local variable `numArr`, then it works perfectly and reverses the array.

```
function reverseArray (arr) {
    var numArr = arr.length;    
    var newArr = [];    
    for (i = 0; i < numArr; i++) {      
        let inArr = arr;
        newArr[i] = inArr.pop(i);       
    }
    return newArr;
}

reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]);

// OUTPUT: ["F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `pop()` doesn’t take any arguments.

Comment: why do you have three arrays? the assingment of an array assigns the object reference. the handed over array is mutated, too.

Comment: @Ry- you're right but in this case, that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pop` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.pop)) is a mutator method: It changes the state of the array you call it on. So naturally, `inArr.pop(1)` modifies `arr` (in your first example), since `inArr` and `arr` both refer to the same array.

Probably worth noting as well that `pop` doesn't accept any parameters, so that `1` doesn't do anything.

In your first example, your best bet is to just assign another variable (say, `j`) the initial value `arr.length - 1` and use `arr[j]` to get the value, then decrease `j` as you increase `i`. (Also, no point to `inArr`, and you need to declare `i` to avoid what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html):

```js
function reverseArray (arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < arr.length; i++, j--) {      
        newArr[i] = arr[j];
    }   
    return newArr;
}
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]));
```

You can also just use `arr[arr.length - i - 1]` rather than a second variable:

```js
function reverseArray (arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {      
        newArr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
    }   
    return newArr;
}
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]));
```

Comment: Makes sense, but then why when (in the second snippet) I assign numArr = arr.length, numArr doesn't keep changing while arr decreases.

Comment: @leonardofed - Because `numArr` has no connection whatsoever to `arr`. `numArr = arr.length` *copies* the value of `length` into `numArr`. There's no ongoing link after that.

Comment: The second solution is not working for the numbers. example: [0,1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: @VenuMadhav - The second solution does work for that array (or any other): https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/nu4pxLkr/

Answer (score 3):

You could take a copy of the array and use the length of the copy for checking the next pop/push command.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    var newArr = [],
        inArr = array.slice();    // take copy of primitive values

    while (inArr.length) {        // check decrementing length
        newArr.push(inArr.pop());
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]));
```

To fullfill the condition, you could use a `for` statement as well.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    var newArr = [],
        inArr = array.slice();    // take copy of primitive values

    for(; inArr.length; ) {       // check decrementing length
        newArr.push(inArr.pop());
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]));
```

Comment: What purpose does using a `for` where a `while` is appropriate serve?

Answer (score 1):

Here It Goes using two For Loops:

```js
let arr = [1, 12, 15, 16, 78, 89, 53];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    let c, a, b;
    b = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = b;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: just ignore variables c and a

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```js
fruit=['banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'lemon'] //array
    
z=[] //empty array

for(i=(fruit.length-1);i>-1;i--){    
  z.push(fruit[i])
}

//i>-1 because the index of array ends at 0
    
console.log(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function reverseArray(a) {
    let arrayLength = a.length
    for (let i = 0; i< arrayLength/2; i ++){
      let temp =  a[i]
    a[i] = a[arrayLength -(i+1)]
    a[arrayLength - (i+1)] = temp
}
return a
}
reverseArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) //expect: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: actually, we can let i < Math.floor(arrayLength) to eliminate the middle element. This case is to not change position of itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first function is that when you `pop` an element from an array `arr` its actually decreasing the length of your array `arr`. That is why you see less results then the original number of elements.

so your code worked like this

```
1st pass: i=0 and arr.length = 6; // 0<6 true
2nd pass: i=1 and arr.length = 5; // 1<5 true
3rd pass: i=2 and arr.length = 4; // 2<4 true
4th pass: i=3 and arr.length = 3; // 3<3 false and it does not execute
```

so you see only three results.

Comment: The OP *could* do that, but it's pointless to modify the source array (or a copy of it) when building the reversed array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have updated my answer. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this code:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    var newString = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       newString += str[i];
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
let output = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) {

    // determine correct array index in respect to the current iteration
    let index = input.length - i;

    // push to new array
    output.push(reverse[index]);
}

// verify result
console.log(output);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar code to reverse an Array.

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]));
//output: ["F","E","D","C","B","A"]
```